# "status": 404 Error for POST Request in Spring Boot CRUD

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, http-post

I developed Spring Boot CRUD application. The database I have connected is PostgreSQL. `@GetMapping` is working properly and an empty array of objects can be retrieved by the GET request. But in `@PostMapping`, the POST request gives a 404 error.

**SpringRecapApplication.java**

```
package com.example.SpringRecap;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = SecurityAutoConfiguration.class)
//@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
//@EnableWebMvc
@RequestMapping(name = "api/v1/customers" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)

public class SpringRecapApplication {
    //dependency injection
    private static  CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public SpringRecapApplication(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringRecapApplication.class, args);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {

        return customerRepository.findAll();

    }

    record NewCustomerRequest(
            String name,
            String email,
            Integer age
    ) {
        @PostMapping
        public void addCustomer(@RequestBody NewCustomerRequest newCustomerRequest) {
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setAge(newCustomerRequest.age());
            customer.setName(newCustomerRequest.name());
            customer.setEmail(newCustomerRequest.email());
            customerRepository.save(customer);
        }
    }

}
```

`customerRepository.save(customer);` doesn't allow to make the dependency injection final. (   `private static  CustomerRepository customerRepository;`). IDEA suggests making it static. But it didn't work. When I was using `@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")`, a 405 error was received. Then I fixed that issue by doing as below,

```
 @RequestMapping(name = "api/v1/customers" ,method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

**CustomerRepository.java**

```
package com.example.SpringRecap;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer,Integer> {
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
package com.example.SpringRecap;

import jakarta.persistence.*;

import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(
            name = "customer_id_sequence",
            sequenceName = "customer_id_sequence",
            allocationSize = 1

    )
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE,
            generator = "customer_id_sequence"

    )
    private Integer id;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private Integer age;

    public Customer(Integer id, String name, String email, Integer age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Customer() {

    }


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(Integer age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Customer customer = (Customer) o;
        return Objects.equals(id, customer.id) && Objects.equals(name, customer.name) && Objects.equals(email, customer.email) && Objects.equals(age, customer.age);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id, name, email, age);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", age=" + age +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Postman:

[image: Postman image]

Please put a comment if further information is needed to get the solution.

Comment: Change this @RequestMapping(name = "api/v1/customers" ,method = RequestMethod.POST) to @RequestMapping(name = "/api/v1") and on @GetMapping("/customers"). This should work. Also make sure that your application is running on port 3000.

Comment: I have clearly mentioned the points I have done with the error I got with a screenshot in Postman, then I will remove the part you have mentioned. @jsotola

Comment: @GovilKumar I did as you mentioned, but it doesn't work. The application is running on port 3000. And GET request is working properly in my code which I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: That was my bad, I meant on @PostMapping("/customers")

Comment: @Govil Kumar No, it's not your bad. I tried as @PostMapping("/customers") but didn't work

Comment: @GovilKumar thank you for the help. Now It's working I implement a DTO. If you preferred I can add the answer I found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you specified the POST endpoint as part of your DTO and not as part of your controller. As your DTO is not a Spring managed bean, Spring won't map the URL to your endpoint. Anyways, you should move your endpoints into a seperate class. Example:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/customers")
public class CustomerController {

    private final CustomerRepository customerRepository;

    public SpringRecapApplication(CustomerRepository customerRepository) {
        this.customerRepository = customerRepository;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Customer> getCustomer() {
        return customerRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    public void addCustomer(@RequestBody NewCustomerRequest newCustomerRequest) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        customer.setAge(newCustomerRequest.age());
        customer.setName(newCustomerRequest.name());
        customer.setEmail(newCustomerRequest.email());
        customerRepository.save(customer);
    }

    // Helper classes

    record NewCustomerRequest(String name, String email, Integer age) { }

}
```

It would be best if you moved your DTO in a seperate class as well. I recommend placing the DTOs in a `dto` package and your controllers in a `controller` package.

Two side notes: you shouldn't expose your entities via your API. You should use DTOs for incoming and outgoing data. Check out [lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) and [mapstruct](https://mapstruct.org/), they make this pretty easy.

Comment: I think you have mentioned Lombok for @Data annotation to remove getters setters,... etc.

Comment: I prefer using record for DTOs -  the use of Lombok is overrated since Java17 IMO

Comment: I tried with DTO. It was working. But  @Autowired should be used to wire the  CustomerRepository. in the constructor I had to use void. but, normally constructors don't have a return type. I assume that void is working there because void doesn't return anything. @ times29

Comment: Thanks, @times29 for the support. Now It's working. I did a small change in the code of yours as I mentioned in the above comment

Comment: @NimashaMadhushani you don't need the `@Autowired` annotation if you have only only constructor in your class. Also, check this article on why you should prefer constructor injection over other mechanisms: https://reflectoring.io/constructor-injection/

Comment: @times29 I have heard your point, but in my code, it was not ok without  Autowired. That's why I changed it.